# How am I supposed to get rid of this notification?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

[image]

The only thing I think this means is that there's some cosmetic I haven't clicked on that I unlocked recently.

The only problem is, I only nearly every operator already.  This is pretty annoying -- I really want to get rid of it without having to sift through every operator, every operator cosmetic (uniform, headgear), every operator weapon, every weapon skin, every charm -- it adds up to a lot of time that I don't like wasting just to get rid of this small notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I had that issue forever and couldn't work it out

I discovered you have to visit each operator, look at all the sections

- Video introduction to operator
- Weapon set up, skins and attachments

After visiting these sections for each operator the notification will disappear

If this doesn't fix the issue, comment and we will try find another solution, however above is what fixed the issue for me!

I know that you don't want to sift threw all operators but that's the only way (I know of any how)